# How to run Drush commands on a schedule?

Tags: drush, cron

I'm deploying content to Drupal remotely (I'm in an Enterprise environment) and I need  something to run Drush commands based on a schedule. E.g on a cron task, read commands from the database table or file, execute the commands and record the result.

I've looked at the Rules and Job Schedule modules, but they don't really work because I need to enable Features.

I was thinking of creating a module which reads commands from a database and executes the commands in php. But is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), which could be described as an advanced version of cron, though it is more powerful than that.  John Smith made a [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/kg4san/drupal-continuous-integration-with-jenkins) about integrating Drupal with Continuous Integration practices.

If you're in an enterprise environment, hopefully you have the resources to get a Jenkins server set up.  You can then also use this to run automated tests, etc. too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Drush with cron, please read [drush topic docs-cron](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/docs/cron.html).  `drush topic` has a lot of interesting information, and is a good place to look when you have questions.