# Crontab to trigger scripts with drush commands

Tags: drush, cron

I've read [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28888/how-to-run-drush-commands-on-a-schedule) and the answers links through to Jenkins. Looked into it but was way over my head to install and set up. 
The other answer links to [this page](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/docs/cron.html) which talks about running cron tasks with drush commands. What I want obviously is the opposite.

With the endgoal in mind of just doing backups and updates, it seemed pretty straightforward the I could create a crontab that triggers a php or sh script with drush commands in it. The only thing I can't seem to find is a way to construct such a script.

I did google this, but I keep getting information to do the opposite thing being trigger cron with drush.

Comment: Could you just clarify, are you asking how to set up a crontab?

Comment: No I know how to set up a crontab. I'm looking for how to make a `.php` file or maybe even `.sh` that has a few drush commands that get excecuted when loaded.

Comment: I'd have to recommend finding a bash scripting/PHP tutorial then, it falls outside of the scope of this site I'm afraid. For example, here's a bash script that makes use of Drush: http://pages.uoregon.edu/vid/2012/06/17/drupal-db-backup-bash-script-with-drush-and-git/. You can use that as a starting block, change what you need to, then invoke it through crontab

Comment: cool, looking into it. Awesome.